# PermissionDenied error while trying to read from Firestore with the Go SDK

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-sdk

I setup a test database with the following configuration rules for development:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I tested it with curl:

```
url -X GET "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/<my-project-id>/databases/(default)/documents/configurations/test"
{
  "name": "projects/<my-project-id>/databases/(default)/documents/configurations/test",
  "fields": {
    "hello": {
      "stringValue": "world"
    }
  },
  "createTime": "2023-10-04T17:23:41.476045Z",
  "updateTime": "2023-10-04T17:23:41.476045Z"
}
```

Then I tried running the equivalent code with a go script:

```
// Firestore test
func readFromFirestore(){

    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, os.Getenv("PROJECT_ID"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error creating firestore client: ", err)
    }
    log.Println("Firestore client: ", client)
    // Creating the documentref
    docref := client.Doc("configurations/test")
    fmt.Println("Document ref: ", docref)
    docsnap, err := docref.Get(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error reading document: ", err)
    }
    dataMap := docsnap.Data()
    fmt.Println(dataMap)
}
```

And I get the following output

```
go run .                                                                               
2023/10/04 14:33:15 Firestore client:  &{0xc00011d590 <my-projectid> (default) 0xc00011d5a8}
Document ref:  &{0xc0002c8160 projects/<my-project-id>/databases/(default)/documents/configurations/test configurations/test test 0xc00011d5f0}
2023/10/04 14:33:16 Error reading document: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Missing or insufficient permissions.
exit status 1
```

All the answers I find online for this error directs me towards configuring firestore security rules. But since I can retrieve the document with an unauthenticated HTTP request, I think this is not the issue. I think I probably made a mistake on my Go implementation.

I've tried searching for the error code, and followed the instructions of the main search results, without success. ChatGPT is also not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

I managed to make it work by setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATON_CREDENTIALS="KEY PATH"` environment variable, where the `KEY_PATH` is the path, relative or absolute, to a JSON credentials file.

This is described in the firestore quickstart for server side libraries.
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/create-database-server-client-library

Not sure yet if there is a way to make this work only by authenticating with the CLI.

EDIT: Found a way to do it with the CLI
`gcloud auth application-default login`

I like this one even better because I don't need to have credential files in my system.